# Google Maps Coordinates Problem

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

I have been trying to use google street maps with the help of OpenLayers, but Every time I am running into a problem with this google maps coordinates.

The Coordinates of a location named *'Asab, in Abu Dhabi'* should have coordinates as 
**"Longitude=54.3004105, Latitude=23.25535006"** but instead it gives coordinates like ***"Long=6036690.74501, Lat=2700367.334"***.

The Code I used to include google maps into my HTML webpage is as below:
var map;

```
function init(){
// Initiating 'map' Variable and Adding Controls
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', {
 controls: [
new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomBox(),
new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomToMaxExtent(),
new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({}),
new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition('mouse_position', { prefix: 'Long: ', separator: ' \n| Lat: '}),
new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine({}),
new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap()
]
});

// BaseMap Layers
var google_streets= new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
'Google Streets', 
{type: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        units: "m",
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34,
                                             20037508.34, 20037508.34),
        maxResolution: 1.40625
}, {"sphericalMercator": true}
);
```

So I have been looking all over to correct this but I am not getting how to do it. I am a new learner into this OpenLayers, so if someone can please give me push it would be really helpful.

Comment: Can it be another projection system that generates those coordinates? You've used WGS 84?

Comment: yes surely any projection system would work as far as it gives us the correct coordinates for locations, when cross-checked on the actual GOOGLE MAPS website

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set on the start of openlayers script with:

```
    function init(){
        var option = {
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
            displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")

        };
```

or in the layer with trasformation

```
            extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds($SO_ln.",".$SO_lt.",".$NE_ln.",".$NE_lt).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'), 
        new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:3857'));
```

Comment: you answer was spot.... thanks a lot
I could only get your 1st method to work and not the 2nd one.

Great answer really! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The first coordinates are in WGS84 longlat degrees EPSG:4326, while the second ones are in Spherical Mercator "metres" , EPSG:3857.

This is what you set the display projection to, so no reason to get worried about.

In QGIS, with a Openstreetmap background, your points look like this:

[image]

Comment: Andre the map you used seems like Open Source Map, whereas mine is Google Maps and unless my coordinates do not come right it is quite a trouble. 

I am using the mouse position control to see the coordinates and they do not seem to be correct. What shall I do?

Comment: Google Map uses the same projection as Openstreetmap. You have to take care about the difference between projection and display projection, as given in another answer.

Comment: Thank u @Andre it actually worked what you suggested to do the way pjhooker said in the answer.
Somehow the pjhooker's 1st idea works and not the second.
But still I am grateful to you people.